# using UDP to parallelize HTTP reads

Tags: http, udp

Apparently, I don't get true parallel reads of different URLs on the same server, even issuing truly contemporary requests, on multiple physical interfaces (NICs).

I think the problem could be that HTTP protocol is connection oriented, then requests are serialized at lower level into TCP/IP stack (is this correct wording?).

Does make sense to attempt to 'reimplement' an high level HTTP request with a connectionless schema, like UDP, and handle myself packet addressing, to speedup streaming ?

Comment: No, the problem is ultimately that the server' hard drive isn't multi-threaded. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @EJP: Some web server implements caching, and I can observe serialization at much lower speeds than actual Internet connection. But you got a point here.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP requests are independent. They can be issues over arbitrarily many independent connections. HTTP does not impose an limits regarding concurrency.

You hit some resource limit. Maybe your client library restricts the number of concurrent calls. Maybe the server does. Maybe the network is fully utilized. Maybe back-end resources that the server uses are maxed out.

Find the bottleneck and eliminate it. The transport protocol is not the problem. Changing it can't help.

> different URLs

Whether the URL is different or not makes no difference, except if the server implements some special throttling. Highly unlikely.

> on multiple physical interfaces (NICs).

You are probably not network-bound.

> requests are serialized at lower level into TCP/IP stack

No. Connection management is not part of HTTP. The client decided how many connections to use. Reconfigure the client.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fairly sure I'm network-bound, because I limit the bandwidth on both interfaces well under the DSL speed, and observe  the speed get halved when I issue a 2 parallel reads

Comment: Also, I'm using libCURL, that beside allowing me to specify the interface on each request, apparently doesn't limit the number of clients. Could be Ubuntu TCP stack implementation that serialize requests ?

Comment: OK, then you might be network bound. How many concurrent requests do you have outstanding at all times and how many per second do you get? How big are the responses on average.; Make sure, keep-alive is enabled. You might be latency-limited.; The TCP stack does not serialize independent connections.

Comment: You have a mistake somewhere. Expect unlimited scalability once it is resolved. Neither TCP not HTTP are problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Does make sense to attempt to 'reimplement' an high level HTTP request with a connectionless schema, like UDP, and handle myself packet addressing, to speedup streaming ?

You will have to re-implement flow control, segment fragmentation, re-transmission and other features of TCP protocol yourself. And then your HTTP implementation will not be compatible with the standard one.

So no, it does not make much sense.

For streaming you may like to use protocols designed for streaming, like [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC).

Comment: Thanks. WebRTC must be implemented on server, I assume ? I'm accessing public data, and I have no control over the source, apart URLs